# Why does the "Question Has Been Closed" banner no longer display until page reload?

Tags: bug, status-review, closed-questions, live-refresh

On SO when helping with a question, if you were working on an answer when the question was closed by others, an orange banner would appear at the top of the browser window telling you the question was closed and is no longer accepting answers. This prevented the continued waste of time working on an answer for a question that was closed by others.

This is no longer happening. You do not receive an indication that a question was closed until you attempt to submit an answer and find the answer button non-responsive or otherwise do something to cause the page to reload. (especially if there is already an answer that prevents you from seeing the question) This seems like a counterpart question to why the timestamp in user comments no longer updates updates unless a page is reloaded. I don't know exactly when it stopped being presented, but I don't recall seeing one since the dark mode beta came out (related?) It may have been since then I cannot be totally sure.

It would be nice to get the functional banner back as it did save a great deal of wasted effort. I don't know if this change was intentional or a bug, but it isn't working anymore. I was working on a CS50 answer yesterday [data argument not used by format string for cs50 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62179117/3422102) and after 20 minutes of work on an answer explaining the differences between field-width and precision using the `"%s"` specifier, I found the question closed when I went to submit. No banner was displayed even though the question had been closed 10 minutes earlier. If it was intentionally deleted -- can we get it back?

Comment: This isn't related to the issue about timestamps in comments not being updated (that has a clear, known reason why it doesn't work). Comment timestamps updating and the closed notification are quite separate, other than that they are both implemented in JavaScript (i.e. if JavaScript isn't running on the page, then very little will be working; this does happen sometimes, but it's quite rare and is unlikely to be the cause of this issue).

Comment: I was able to duplicate this in my first of three attempts, but not the second two. On the page where this did occur, the editor was **not** making any POST calls to `/posts/{id}/editor-heartbeat/answer` (which is the POST which gets the response that produces the user visible notification; there should be a call to this endpoint every 45 seconds), but was making the scheduled POST calls to `/posts/validate-body`. My other attempts appeared to function normally.

Comment: In one of the pages, I noted that when I left the page alone for a while the `editor-heartbeat/answer` endpoint stopped being called and did not resume being called if editing was resumed some time later (calling the `validate-body` endpoint was resumed). So, the problem you're experiencing could also happen after you started answering, then paused for some time, and resumed again. Overall, it appears that this notification should be based on the WebSocket (which does indicate question closure), either in addition to or instead of the call to the `editor-heartbeat/answer` endpoint.

Comment: "*if you were working on an answer when the question was closed by others, an orange banner would appear at the top of the browser window telling you the question was closed*" for the record, my experience was that the banner didn't always work. Sometimes it would show up, other times it wouldn't. It seemed pretty flaky to begin with.

Comment: Well, I'm just glad others have experienced it and it is repeatable -- some of the time. At least now it can be looked into. It's more one of those curiosities that after being hear for a half-decade you just notice and wonder -- why that didn't work this time?. Depending on the depth of an answer, I can edit for 30 minutes or so, with maybe a 5 minute break depending on what kind of trouble the kids are getting into.... Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: This was never very reliable.  Stack Exchange has stated on a number of occasions that questions can still be answered up to 4 hours or so after they are closed, if you opened a window before the question was closed, and that this is *by design.*